# can't allow users to like individual pages on site, getting max canonical URL count exceeded

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-like

I have like buttons on about 8 pages on my site. I have a module which appears on those 8 pages. On every page on my site, og:url is set to return the current page's URL using `content="http://dogboken.com', $domain . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ,'"` but now I am getting an error saying that I "cannot exceed max canonical URL count specified in sitevar."

I've searched but have found no solution. What is the proper way to make this work? I want the posts on users' pages to link to the page they clicked the like button on, not my homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is likely the cause of your issue. The REQUEST_URI is whatever the user typed or used to get to your site. This can be a lot of things such as /index.html, /index.html/, index.html?q=searching, etc. Since your user's are typing in or using different URLs for the same content, you're getting too many "canonical URLs". Facebook want's the one URL you consider to be the URL for the page. I don't know how your URLs are created on your site but a typical thing to do would be to use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] instead of REQUEST_URI. You'll have to see how  your framework generates URLs and see if there's something you can use for the canonical URL.

Comment: Looks like this is what's causing the problem. It's spitting PHP Session IDs in left and right and ruining my life. I'll have to find a way around it. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that not every page in SMF has a canonical URL. Is there any way to tell facebook's crawler to strip the session ID from the url?

Comment: You'll have to strip the session on your end in PHP. The best option is to actually turn off sessions in the URL as this causes potential security risks and other headaches. This URL should help you with that http://www.frozenminds.com/disable-sessionid.html

Comment: Thank you! Since I can't get a perfect Canonical URL generated using my software, this option has helped to fix the problem and has given me another way to generate a Canonical URL (using the code on that link which strips the session ID data from the URL).